# How to close a startup window

Tags: c#, wpf

I have C# WPF application that has a login windows as it's startup URI. I want to close the the startup window, which is the login window when the combination of username and password is correct.

I have this code

```
var username = query.username;
var password = query.password;

if (userTexbox.Text == username.ToString() && passwordbox.Password == password.ToString())
{
    var entity = new Log
    {
        user = userTexbox.Text,
        dateTime = DateTime.Now.ToString()
    };
    logCollection.Insert(entity);

    Mainwindow main = new MainWindow();
    this.Close();
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("User not found/Wrong credentials", "Re-enter Credentials");
}
```

But even with the Close() method, the login window is still visible although not active.

Comment: the only reason that your window does not close is probably that some operation in your Mainwindow constructor or logCollection.Insert is blocking so your code never actually reaches this.Close(), if you put a break point on the Close line you will notice that its never reached.

Answer (score 2):

Change the logic: set the main window as startup window, then display the login window from main window. Check the bellow code, it's for the main window's contructor:

```
...
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    //--init main windows minimized
    WindowState = System.Windows.WindowState.Minimized;

    Loaded +=
        delegate
        {
            //hide main window
            Hide();

            //initialize the login window
            var loginWin = new LoginWindow
            {
                WindowStartupLocation = System.Windows.WindowStartupLocation.CenterScreen,
                WindowStyle = System.Windows.WindowStyle.SingleBorderWindow,
            };

            loginWin.Closed += delegate
            {
                //check login result (OK)
                if (loginWin.Result != LoginResult.Success)
                    Application.Current.Shutdown(1);

                //--display the main window
                Show();
                WindowState = System.Windows.WindowState.Normal;
                Focus();
            };

            //show&focus the login
            loginWin.Show();
            loginWin.Focus();
        };
}
...
```

I hope it helps.

***EDIT***

Here the `LoginWindow` code behind.

```
public partial class LoginWindow : Window
{
    public LoginResult Result { get; private set; }

    public LoginWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void ButtonLogin_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //example login button
        Result = DoLogin();
        Close();
    }

    private LoginResult DoLogin()
    {
        //NOTE: Add your login logic here (for now sucess response)
        return LoginResult.Success;
    }
}

public enum LoginResult
{
    Unknow,
    Success,
    Failed
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what the loginWin.Result is trying to imply, is it a variable from the loginWindow?

Comment: @fredpedro `loginWin.Result` will store the login result, for example: it can be an Enum like `public enum LoginResult { Unknown, Failed, Success}`. I hope it helps. Let me know if you need more help.

Answer (score 0):

What you are missing here is Assignment of MainWindow

```
Application.Current.MainWindow = main;
```

After creating new instance of MainWindow if you assign it the Application.Current.MainWindow (before closing the login window) then it has a main window to continue the STA thread and the LoginWindow thread can be released.

Do let me know if this helps.